# Get latest StreamProvider value in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

How do I get the latest value of a stream provider in flutter?
Here is my situation.
I have a widget where I am listening to a provider and eventually rebuild the widget.

```
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
        final dbData = ref.watch(dbProvider);
        return dbData.when(
         data: (entries) {
            //do something
```

Whenever I update the database the build is called multiple times with old data as well as with the new ones. Since I use the new data for further tasks, I am running into errors.
Is there a way to listen just for the latest values?

Thanks.

Comment: StreamProvider always gives you the latest data available.
There's never a case where it sends you both the old and new data at the same time.

Comment: At least the build() method is called at least twice. First with the old data and then with the latest.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. The call with the old data is most likely a loading state. Check isLoading/isRefreshing/isReloading